# My graphics tablet won't work under Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, graphics-tablet

I'm trying to get my graphics tablet to work under Ubuntu 17.04, but it's not being recognized (light is blinking but the tablet doesn't do anything). It does work on Windows, but there aren't any drivers for Linux. It's a Medion MD 41217.

I found that it's the same tablet as the Aiptek APT-2 but installing the drivers for that device (according to [this post on Linux hardware guide](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2015-05-11-aiptek-apt-2-tablet-usb-graphics-tablet)) didn't work, the drivers are in place and my tablet is being recognized as an APT-2 tablet but it won't work.

Here are the file contents/terminal outputs that should be useful.

[link to ubuntu pastebins](http://bridgeurl.com/ubuntu-pastebin-links)
(had to group them because I can only make 2 links)

Does anyone know how I can make my tablet work under Ubuntu?